# Express Multer Not able to upload Large(more then 6MB) files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, multer

I have an Upload feature in my application, which works fine for file size less than 6MB.

When I upload that PDF, in response, I am getting index.html page with 200 status. Need help to debug this issue.

Please find my sample PDF here: [Click here to download sample pdf](https://www.docdroid.net/7VO8rVm/sample-pdf.pdf)

My server detail is centos 7 and apache server.

I am using axios call in react:

```
    try {
      const { data } = await axios(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${sessionStorage.token}` }}
      );
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      checkError();
      throw error;
    }
```

Server index.js file:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Server Reoute code:

```
orderRouter.route("/uploaddoc").post(validateToken, upload.array('doc'), Order.uploadDoc);
```

Multer code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
     callback(null, './files/order');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
     callback(null, file.originalname.split('.')[0] + "_" + Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[1]); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to add a console log in Multer destination and in validationToken function too but not getting any logs. Where I can put logs so that I can get the exact exception on upload.

Comment: Instead of FormData and Multer, I sent the file as base64 and converted back to file on the server and followed this link for implementation.

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asynchronous-file-upload-react

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FormData and Multer, I sent the file as base64 and converted back to file on the server and followed this link for implementation. [pluralsight.com/guides/asynchronous-file-upload-react](https://pluralsight.com/guides/asynchronous-file-upload-react)